# Which group is C0?

Tags: group-theory, sagemath

This is likely a silly question, but I cannot find an answer on the internet. I used Sage-math to find the structure of a group presented as:

$$\langle x,y; xy=1 \rangle$$

It returned C0: which group is it?

**EDIT** Here is the code I used

```
sage: G.<x,y,z,t>=FreeGroup()                                                                        
sage: H=G.quotient([x*y,x*z,x*t])                                                                    
sage: H.structure_description()                                                                      
'C0'
```

Comment: Could you provide the exact code you use so everyone can try for themselves?

Comment: @user2661923 Must probably, as is standard use, they write $\;1\; for the multiplicative unit element of that group.

Comment: Perhaps the notation is $C_n=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, hence $C_0=\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Gae.S. That's a sound assumption, but better if the OP checks that directly.

Comment: I thought Sage used GAP, but GAP gives "Z" as the structure description of the infinite cyclic group.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I've definitely seen $C_0$; it gives a neat way to state the invariant factor decomposition for finitely generated abelian groups without having to separate out the torsionfree part, for example, since you can just have $n_1|n_2|\cdots|n_k$, with a bunch of $0$s at the end.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, I have seen this, too. I also have seen $C_{\infty}$ and who knows what becomes of $0$ or $\infty$ when typing it somewhere with letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what $\;C_0\;$ means, but that group of yours is $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , the infinite cyclic group (though you wrote it multiplicatively). Observe that from the unique relation given, we get

$$xy=1\implies y=x^{-1}\implies K:=\langle x, y\;|\; xy=1\rangle=\langle x,x^{-1}\rangle =\langle x\rangle\cong\Bbb Z$$

Comment: $C_n$ is the cyclic group where the generator has order $n$. $C_0$ is not an uncommon notation for the infinite cyclic group, as it lets you state the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups without having to separate out the torsion free part. Also, $0$ is the nonnegative generator of the ideal $\{n\in\mathbb{Z}\mid x^n=e\}$, and that generator is the “order” of the element/group.